# Rotating div on hover, but without making it rotate back on hover off, pure CSS

Tags: css

I created a div that on hover changes shape into a circle, rotates and changes its background. It works fine, but after moving a mouse outside of it I don't want it to rotate back, I just want it to go back to previous state. How can I do this?

Code:

html:

```css
.rotatingdiv{
  position: absolute;
  background: url(pictures/picture1.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: max(30vw, 300px);
  background-position: right 0 top 0;*/
  background-attachment: relative;
  left: 50vw;
  top: max(40%, 200px);
  height: 10vw;
  width: 20vw;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 200px;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(255,255,255,0.9);
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 3px black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: black solid;  
  border-radius: 10%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.rotatingdiv:hover{
  height: 15vw;
  width: 15vw;
  min-height: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;   
  background: url(pictures/picture2.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: min(-4vw, -40px) 10%;
  background-attachment: relative;
  background-size: max(20vw, 200px);
  transform: translate(min(2.5vw, 25px), min(-2.5vw,-25px)) rotate(360deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotatingdiv">Rotate</div>
```

Comment: You can look into this: https://css-tricks.com/different-transitions-for-hover-on-hover-off/

Comment: I tried this aproach, but it doesnt work well with my positioning or im doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the `transition` property of the `.rotatingdiv` (but keep it on `:hover`) it will apply the unhovered CSS without any transition.

```css
.rotatingdiv{
  position: absolute;
  background: url(pictures/picture1.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: max(30vw, 300px);
  background-position: right 0 top 0;*/
  background-attachment: relative;
  left: 50vw;
  top: max(40%, 200px);
  height: 10vw;
  width: 20vw;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 200px;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(255,255,255,0.9);
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 3px black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: black solid;  
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.rotatingdiv:hover{
  height: 15vw;
  width: 15vw;
  min-height: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;   
  background: url(pictures/picture2.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: min(-4vw, -40px) 10%;
  background-attachment: relative;
  background-size: max(20vw, 200px);
  transform: translate(min(2.5vw, 25px), min(-2.5vw,-25px)) rotate(360deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotatingdiv">Rotate</div>
```

Comment: This will make  the div go back to previous state instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer to this. Instead of using translation I declared the positioning by left and top property in both classes, leaving rotation as an only transformation and in .rotatingdiv I've put:

```
transition: all 0.5s ease, transform 0s ease;
```

This makes all changes run back smoothly, except rotation that happens instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Specify fill-mode on your animated element :

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

So you don't have reverse animation.